# Retrieve field from map array

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

In a document, I have an array list. Each one contains a map which contains multiple fields like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/La18Q.png).

How can I retrieve a specific field from that array? For example, to retrieve "field 3", what should I do?

Comment: Moreover, your question is how to extract data from a JSON array!! correct? Exporting data in firebase gives you its raw type, which is JSON and you can post it here in question.

Comment: So you want to retrieve the value for `"field 3"` property from a single child or from all children? Show as a more detailed screenshot of your database. Please also respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo Okay what's really going is that this image is a field for who has seen the message in a group chat. A document represents a single message with all of its details. It contains fields like the message, the date it has been sent, who has sent it...and an array list called "seen by" which holds who has seen that message. I want to check if the user who has sent the message is the same user who has seen it. If yes, then nothing is done; else, the list will be updated with a new map with the same elements which are the user id and the date when the user has seen it.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of Arraylist of maps.

**Iterate through every map object in your arraylist. While iterating, look for the keys whose values you want to extract.**

```
 ArrayList<Map<String, String>> itemData = new ArrayList<>();

         Map<String , String> map1=new HashMap<String, String>();
         map1.put("field1","usman");
         map1.put("field2","30");
         map1.put("field3","172");

        Map<String , String> map2=new HashMap<>();
        map2.put("field1","ahmad");
        map2.put("field2","32");
        map2.put("field3","180");
        itemData.add(map1);
        itemData.add(map2);


         for(Map<String,String> value:itemData){
            String result=value.get("field3");
            Log.d("TAG",result);
         }
```

You need to iterate through every map in your arraylist. While iterating, look for the keys whose values you want to extract.

Comment: Actually I didn't get it. And those 2 maps are in a single array list.